# Regex for password policy not working

Tags: .net, regex

I have been given the task to validate a password when its about to be changed.
The password needs:

- to be a minimum of 8 characters long
- have at least one uppercase letter
- have at least one lowercase letter
- have at least one digit
- have at least one special charachter

This is the regex I'm using:

```
^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%&+=-_]).*$
```

Since I'm not an expert on regular expressions, I have been following a [tutorial on Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-30-Minute-Regex-Tutorial) (which I have found very helpful). Though I spent more than than 30mins reading the tutorial, I still can't grasp what the problem is.

**The problem:**
The regex looks for everything but the special characters. I don't see the problem.

While I was searching for answers, I came across the [derekslager.com blog](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx) which has a pretty good page for testing expressions.

Comment: Try this `((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{8,20})`

Comment: you have a double backslash before the d `(?=.*\\d)`. Try removing it and it should work. The way you have it, you would request your password to contain `\d` (literally) at least once instead of "at least one digit"

Comment: ....I mean remove the double backlash, leave just one, like this: `(?=.*\d)`

Comment: Still not working the way it is suppose to. to clarify:
It can recognize the special characters BUT if i type in a password that does NOT have an special character then it still says that it is valid. Example: "Password123" should be invalid but the regex says that it is valid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a subtle flaw in your regex:

```
[@#$%&+=-_]
        ^
```

A dash within a character class specifies a [character range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#PositiveGroup), meaning your character class will register a "positive" match if any of the following characters are in your password:

> @, #, $, %, &, +, =, >, ?, @, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z, [, \, ], ^, _

If you transpose the `-` and `_`, you can avoid this issue:

```
[@#$%&+=_-]
```

Dashes located either at the first or last position within a character class lose their special meaning and are treated as literal dashes.

In addition, you do not need the `.*` at the beginning and end of your pattern. Your zero-width assertions (aka "lookaheads") already contain `.*`, so this is redundant and will just cause your regex to slow down on negative matches. If you are only using the regex to test an input, then you can begin at the first character and don't need to capture anything:

```
"^(?=.{8,})(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%&+=_-])"
```

If you want to capture the password as well, then you can use:

```
"^(?=.{8,})(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%&+=_-]).*"
```

Just for giggles, if you want to set a maximum bound on passwords you could do so from within your first lookahead:

```
^(?=.{8,30}$)
```

If you want to allow your users to include carriage returns in their passwords, be sure to use the [Singleline flag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx).

See the regex at work on [regexplanet.com](http://fiddle.re/kxfva) and [regexhero.net](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=d89dd22a-4db9-4e33-b3c1-1b69c8bf26c4)

Comment: First of all thanks for taking the time to provide sucha detailed answer. I am using this http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx site to test the soloution(s) that you have provided but none of them are giving me a match. The regex in my code is built up using a stringbuilder and i would have to change every little part. I don't mind doing this if im sure that it will work but it has not passed the "test" site that im using which makes me doubt that it would work?.

Comment: @Ra3IDeN - I obviously can't speaking toward how you are building the regex since you've not posted that code, but this regex *will* match according the parameters you laid out. I've updated my answer with a link. (Are you performing this match on the client side using javascript? If so, then your lookaheads are not supported because they contain [infinite repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).)

Comment: I don't know if something is wrong with you link but i am getting errors when i try it..."Error when compiling regex"

I did not share the string builde code since i initialy thought that it would be a burden for you/others to look through that code, i focused on the regex alone. It is not done in javascript it is done in the backend code

Comment: @Ra3IDeN - You need to click the ".NET" button. "GO" is a different engine that does not support some of the features in this regex. If you follow the link and click the ".NET" button, you see that I tested the regex against "ThisW1llM@tch" and "ThisW1llN0tM4tch". The first was successful, the second was not (because it does not contain any special characters). I've update my answer with a second link to a .NET-only website for confirmation that it *does* work.

Comment: thank you @Cyborgx37! Sorry for my late reply I've had connection problems since yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Someone correct me if im wrong but if the password can be any combination of the requirments you are looking for you may need to validate them one at a time, but if the pattern will always be the same, then one line of regex should do the trick, for instance if it will always be like so:

```
Qwe12;,.  
[Capital Letter(s)][lowercase letter(s)][number(s)][special character(s)]
```

Then one line of regex would be relatively easy to come up with to validate it but if it can be any combination of your requirments e.g.

```
weQ,.12
```

or

```
12we,.Q
```

Then it may be easier to validate one at a time so:

```
First check for caps [A-Z]
Then lowercase [a-z]
Then numbers [0-9]
Then special characters [[\^$.|?*+()]
```

Therefore if any of these fail password is invalid, hope this helps.

Comment: You are incorrect. A zero-width assertion allows "probing" ahead to find a particular pattern without acutally "moving" the position. It's essentially like "peeking" ahead in a queue or stack without actually "popping". (This is possible because the .NET regex flavor allows unbounded expressions in a lookahead/behind)

Comment: That said, checking for each condition one at a time is not a terrible idea. It would be very useful if, say, you wanted to give admins the ability to enable/disable certain password checks or you wanted to allow extensibility (plugging in custom password validators), etc. Sometimes the one-liner approach creates rigidity within a system that can be undesirable.

Comment: Cool thanks for correcting me I was unaware you could probe ahead